# Similar method to ResolveUrl for using from a static class?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm building a WebPart for Microsoft SharePoint 2010.

Which method could I use from a static class that does the same than `ResolveUrl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Sep/18/ResolveUrl-without-Page (in the comments)

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a site relative HTTP path from a partial path starting out with a ~.
/// Same syntax that ASP.Net internally supports but this method can be used
/// outside of the Page framework.
/// 
/// Works like Control.ResolveUrl including support for ~ syntax
/// but returns an absolute URL.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="originalUrl">Any Url including those starting with ~</param>
/// <returns>relative url</returns>
public static string ResolveUrl(string originalUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(originalUrl))
        return originalUrl;

    // *** Absolute path - just return
    if (IsAbsolutePath(originalUrl))
        return originalUrl;

    // *** We don't start with the '~' -> we don't process the Url
    if (!originalUrl.StartsWith("~"))
        return originalUrl;

    // *** Fix up path for ~ root app dir directory
    // VirtualPathUtility blows up if there is a 
    // query string, so we have to account for this.
    int queryStringStartIndex = originalUrl.IndexOf('?');
    if (queryStringStartIndex != -1)
    {
        string queryString = originalUrl.Substring(queryStringStartIndex);
        string baseUrl = originalUrl.Substring(0, queryStringStartIndex);

        return string.Concat(
            VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(baseUrl),
            queryString);
    }
    else
    {
        return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(originalUrl);
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// This method returns a fully qualified absolute server Url which includes
/// the protocol, server, port in addition to the server relative Url.
/// 
/// Works like Control.ResolveUrl including support for ~ syntax
/// but returns an absolute URL.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ServerUrl">Any Url, either App relative or fully qualified</param>
/// <param name="forceHttps">if true forces the url to use https</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ResolveServerUrl(string serverUrl, bool forceHttps)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverUrl))
        return serverUrl;

    // *** Is it already an absolute Url?
    if(IsAbsolutePath(serverUrl))
        return serverUrl;

    string newServerUrl = ResolveUrl(serverUrl);
    Uri result = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, newServerUrl);

    if (!forceHttps)
        return result.ToString();
    else
        return ForceUriToHttps(result).ToString();

}

/// <summary>
/// This method returns a fully qualified absolute server Url which includes
/// the protocol, server, port in addition to the server relative Url.
/// 
/// It work like Page.ResolveUrl, but adds these to the beginning.
/// This method is useful for generating Urls for AJAX methods
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ServerUrl">Any Url, either App relative or fully qualified</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ResolveServerUrl(string serverUrl)
{
    return ResolveServerUrl(serverUrl, false);
}

/// <summary>
/// Forces the Uri to use https
/// </summary>
private static Uri ForceUriToHttps(Uri uri)
{
    // ** Re-write Url using builder.
    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
    builder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
    builder.Port = 443;

    return builder.Uri;
}

private static bool IsAbsolutePath(string originalUrl)
{
    // *** Absolute path - just return
    int IndexOfSlashes = originalUrl.IndexOf("://");
    int IndexOfQuestionMarks = originalUrl.IndexOf("?");

    if (IndexOfSlashes > -1 &&
         (IndexOfQuestionMarks < 0 ||
          (IndexOfQuestionMarks > -1 && IndexOfQuestionMarks > IndexOfSlashes)
          )
        )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx
You could make use of the ToAbsolute or ToAppRelative methods in order to simulate the functionality

Comment: VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute it's the best solution. Thx :)